# Error handling with axios method in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

If getting response like this-
 data: Array(0)
length: 0

How to handling the error and how to show message the no matching  data found in vuejs.

Comment: Is this an error or an empty response?

Comment: getting response. data: Array(0) length: 0 is an empty response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should either wrap your axios request with try/catch if using async/await, or simply use then..catch methods.

Here's a simple example

```
axios.get('http://api.com')
.then((response) => {
 if (response.data.length === 0) { // Lets check if response contains any items
   // Do Your 'no items found' logic here
   console.log('No items found')
   return
 } else { // We have items, handle them here!
   // We have some items, lets log them
   console.log(response.data)
 }
})
.catch((error) => {
  // Catch and handle any errors here
  console.log(error)
})
```

Comment: I am write code like this but not working--> this.axios.get('/get_law_full/' + this.id)
            .then((response) => {
              if(response.data.length ===0){
                this.$toaster.error('No matching Data Found')
              }
              else{
                console.log(response);
                this.law = response.data;
              }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              this.$toaster.error('No matching Data Found')
            })

Comment: "Not working" doesn't give me anything to go about with. 

Create a proper jsfiddle, give me a screenshot or a log of Your error or anything else relevant because it's impossible to help You in any other way.